# How to validate select input field using React Hook Form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, react-md

I'm trying to validate a form made using form fields from [React MD](https://react-md.dev/) by using React Hook Form. The text input fields are working fine.

But the **validations aren't working** on the select field. Here is the code:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="salutation"
  defaultValue=""
  rules={{ required: "Salutation is required" }}
  disabled={isSubmitting}
  render={(props) => (
     <Select
       id="salutation"
       {...props}
       label="Salutation"
       options={SALUTATION_ITEMS}
       value={salutationValue}
       onChange={(e) => handleSalutationChange(e)}
       disableLeftAddon={false}
       rightChildren={
          <RiArrowDownSFill className="dropDownArrow" />
       }
     />
   );
  }}
/>
```

The error persists even after the user selects a value:

```
{errors.salutation && (
  <div className="validation-alert msg-error ">
    <p>{errors.salutation.message}</p>
  </div>
)}
```

I'm probably missing something or doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing `props.value` and `props.onChange(e)` and you may not need `handleSalutationChange(e)`:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="salutation"
  defaultValue=""
  rules={{ required: "Salutation is required" }}
  disabled={isSubmitting}
  render={(props) => (
     <Select
       id="salutation"
       {...props}
       label="Salutation"
       options={SALUTATION_ITEMS}
       value={props.value} // This one: props.value
       onChange={(e) => {
         props.onChange(e)   // I think you are missing this
         handleSalutationChange(e) // NOT Needed ?
       }}
       disableLeftAddon={false}
       rightChildren={
          <RiArrowDownSFill className="dropDownArrow" />
       }
     />
   );
  }}
/>
```